# Intuit Partner Platform Monthly Connection Billing

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

This page:

[Intuit Billing](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Managing_Your_App/2000_Billing_for_IA)

States Intuit charges $5.00 per month for each connection.  Does that mean if one connection (on every day of each month) is made the charge would 30 x $5 = $150?  Or does it mean one charge of $5 regardless if connecting 100 times on a particular company file/user during a given month?

Comment: The charge is $5 per connected company file, per month. It is NOT a "per HTTP connection" fee, it's a "per connected company" fee. So, $5 regardless of how many actual HTTP connections you make.

Comment: Please answer in form of an 'answer' so I can accept.  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every QuickBooks company that you connect to, that is considered one connection. You can connect and disconnect to that same company as many times as you want in the 30 day free trial, after that if you connect its $5 per month. You have unlimited access to the data for that connection

thanks
Jarred